# Cake PHP revisioning data/id refresh

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

So here is what I am trying to do.

I have one form which will post data to two tables say table a and table b. Now when I edit the same record I want that data in one table should be updated and in other table it should create new row and add the data.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this in cakephp

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving, if the primary key (usually `id`) of the model is given, cakephp will `update`, otherwise it will `insert`.

Comment: I didn't understand can you please elobrate.

Comment: If you're saving a model `User`, and your `data` is `array('User' => array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'ori', ...))`, then because the id is provided in the data then cakephp will update the row in the users table that has that id. If id is missing, a new record will be inserted.    If you need more clarifications, edit your question to provide more data (what your form looks like, how you save your models, what you've already tried)